# What good are my emotions?

Tags: animal-crossing-happy-home-designer

I keep earning emotions when I complete designs for customers. They're not all good emotions, either. What are they good for? How do they work?

Comment: Another one for the [out-of-context titles list](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat)...

Comment: As long as there are games, there will be out of context titles. I don't think that list needs to have every single one. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in ACNL they're just for expressing yourself, though without peer to peer multiplayer there's much less use for them. You can see other villagers nearby reacting to your emotion though--they act a little worried when you're angry, nervously chuckle at the "oops" emotion, smile when you do and so on.